# CREATE TEMP TABLE BASED ON SELECT DISTINCT ON 3 COLUMNS BUT WITH 1 EXTRA COLUMN

Tags: sql, sql-server, distinct, temp-tables

I need to make a temporary file with in it:

Partcode, MutationDate, MovementType, Qty

Every partcode has multiple mutationdates per Movementtype (there are max 9 movementtypes possible)
I need to get the last mutationdate per movementtype per partcode and the quantity that goes with that.

An example with partcode 003307

```
003307 2018-05-31 1 -100
003307 2018-06-11 2 -33
003307 2018-04-25 3 +25
```

and so on for all 9 movementtypes.

What did I get so far:

```
create table #LMUT(
    MutationDate T_Date
    ,PartCode T_Code_Part
    ,CumInvQty T_Quantum_Qty10_3
    ,MovementType T_Type_PMOverInvt
    )

    insert #LMUT(
    MutationDate,
    Partcode,
    CumInvQty,
    MovementType)
    SELECT
    cast (max(MOV.MutationDate) as date)
    ,MOV.PartCode
    ,INV.MutationQty
    ,INV.PMOverInvtType
    FROM dbo.T_PartMovementMain as MOV
    inner join dbo.T_PartMovementOverInvt as INV on

INV.PMMainCode=MOV.PMMainCode
        WHERE
        MOV.PartMovementType = 1
        group by MOV.PartCode,INV.PMOverInvtType,INV.MutationQty,MOV.MutationDate

SELECT * FROM #LMUT where partcode='003007'
drop table #LMUT
```

results in:

```
    2016-12-06 00:00:00.000 003007 -24.000 2
    2016-09-29 00:00:00.000 003007 -24.000 2
    2016-11-09 00:00:00.000 003007 -24.000 2
    2016-11-22 00:00:00.000 003007 -24.000 2
    2016-10-26 00:00:00.000 003007 -24.000 2
    2016-09-12 00:00:00.000 003007 -42.000 2
    2016-10-13 00:00:00.000 003007 -24.000 2
    2016-12-03 00:00:00.000 003007 100.000 5
    2017-01-12 00:00:00.000 003007 -48.000 2
    2016-10-04 00:00:00.000 003007 306.000 7
```

Not what I need, still have 8 times type 2

What else have I tried:

```
SELECT distinct MOV.Partcode,INV.PMOverInvtType,mov.MutationDate
        FROM dbo.T_PartMovementMain as MOV
        inner join dbo.T_PartMovementOverInvt as INV on
        INV.PMMainCode=MOV.PMMainCode
        WHERE
        mov.MutationDate = (SELECT MAX (c.MutationDate) FROM
        dbo.T_PartMovementMain as c
        inner join dbo.T_PartMovementOverInvt as d on D.PMMainCode=c.PMMainCode
                             WHERE
                                     C.PartMovementType = 1 AND
                                     C.PartCode=mov.PartCode AND
                                     D.PMMainCode = C.PMMainCode AND
                                     D.PMOverInvtType=inv.PMOverInvtType                                     
                                    )        
         and MOV.PartMovementType = 1 and mov.partcode='003007'
        order by MOV.Partcode,INV.PMOverInvtType
```

Results in:

```
3007    2   2017-01-12 00:00:00.000
3007    5   2016-12-03 00:00:00.000
3007    7   2016-10-04 00:00:00.000
```

That is what I want but I need to get the Qty too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `row_number()` window function

```
   with cte as

(         SELECT  MOV.*,INV.*,
          row_number() over(partition by INV.PMOverInvtType order by MOV.MutationDate desc)rn
            FROM dbo.T_PartMovementMain as MOV
            inner join dbo.T_PartMovementOverInvt as INV on
            INV.PMMainCode=MOV.PMMainCode
) select cte.* from cte where rn=1
```

Comment: It works! thx. I had never heard of this 'with' function and row_number.

Comment: with cte as
(         SELECT  MOV.Partcode,INV.PMOverInvtType,mov.MutationDate,INV.MutationQty,
          row_number() over(partition by MOV.Partcode,INV.PMOverInvtType order by MOV.Partcode,INV.PMOverInvtType,MOV.MutationDate desc) rn
            FROM dbo.T_PartMovementMain as MOV
            inner join dbo.T_PartMovementOverInvt as INV on INV.PMMainCode=MOV.PMMainCode
) 
select cte.* from cte where rn=1   

This is the code I'm using now.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it like this:

```
  create table #LMUT(
   PartCode     T_Code_Part
   ,MovementType T_Type_PMOverInvt
   ,MutationDate T_Date 
   ,CumInvQty    T_Quantum_Qty10_3
   )

insert #LMUT(Partcode,MovementType,MutationDate,CumInvQty)
    select Artikel,Type,Datum,Aant
    from (
        SELECT  MOV.Partcode as Artikel,INV.PMOverInvtType as Type,mov.MutationDate as Datum,INV.MutationQty as Aant,
          row_number() over(partition by MOV.Partcode,INV.PMOverInvtType order by MOV.Partcode,INV.PMOverInvtType,MOV.MutationDate desc) rn
            FROM dbo.T_PartMovementMain as MOV
            inner join dbo.T_PartMovementOverInvt as INV on INV.PMMainCode=MOV.PMMainCode) cse
    where rn=1
select * from #LMUT  order by Partcode  
drop table #LMUT
```